# boto3: how much time does it takes to upload a file to S3

Tags: python, boto3

I am using boto3 to upload a file in a bucket in S3. With a code like that:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=USERNAME,
                      aws_secret_access_key=PASSWORD,
                      region_name=REGION)
try:
    s3.upload_file(S3_FILE_NAME, BUCKET, LOCAL_FILE_NAME))
```

Is there a way to know how much time the upload takes like for requests?

```
response = requests.request(method, url, params)
response.elapsed.total_seconds()
```

I didn't find any good documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add start time and end time in your boto3 script.

something like

```
import datetime
start=datetime.datetime.now()
# do stuff
end=datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: This is what I am using in the mean time but I wanted something out of the box from boto3

Comment: Only with boto3 it's not possible . Boto3 is python library and we need to apply logic on python level.